# can php function parameters be passed in different order as defined in declaration

Tags: php

Suppose I have a function/method F() that takes 3 parameters $A, $B and $C defined as this.

```
function F($A,$B,$C){
  ...
}
```

Suppose I don't want to follow the order to pass the parameters, instead can I make a call like this?

```
F($C=3,$A=1,$B=1);
```

instead of

```
F(1,2,3)
```

Comment: Don't get me wrong but, what's the point of this when the produced code will be a completely mess?

Comment: Think of other languages like R. You have a plot function with, I don't know, >20 parameters. They all have names and the majority is optional, just the data is mandatory. You can decide to give more parameters to customize plotting by giving a pair `name = value`. This does not produce a mess and is IMO quite nice. Thus, the question has a point at least.

Comment: Python supports this also.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Absolutely not.

One way you'd be able to pass in unordered arguments is to take in an associative array:

```
function F($params) {
   if(!is_array($params)) return false;
   //do something with $params['A'], etc...
}
```

You could then invoke it like this:

```
F(array('C' => 3, 'A' => 1, 'B' => 1));
```

Comment: can you say why not ?

Comment: In newer version of PHP you can also use calling:
`F(["C" => 3, "A" => 1, "B" => 1]);`

Comment: php@8 will feature named arguments.

Answer (score 2):

No, but you could pass in an associative array to handle this:

```
f(array('C'=>3, 'A'=>1, 'B'=>1));
```

and then access it by:

```
function f($obj)
{
   $c = $obj['C'];
}
```

Comment: can you say why not ?

Answer (score 2):

PHP doesn't have named arguments, so the short answer is no. There are two solutions I can find, although neither are all that fantastic.

You could define your function to take its arguments as an array, like [this](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/pcook/ch06_05.htm):

```
function image($img) {
    $tag  = '<img src="' . $img['src'] . '" ';
    $tag .= 'alt="' . ($img['alt'] ? $img['alt'] : '') .'">';
    return $tag;
}

$image = image(array('src' => 'cow.png', 'alt' => 'cows say moo'));
$image = image(array('src' => 'pig.jpeg'));
```

That method unfortunately requires that you modify your function, and as a result I don't like it. The other option is to use [this wrapper class](http://blog.perplexedlabs.com/2009/04/22/php-named-parameters/) which lets you use named arguments in one of the following ways:

```
$obj->method(array('key' => 'value', 'key2' => 'value2'));
$obj->method(':key = value', ':key2 = value2');
```

Answer (score 2):

Starting with php@8, [php will suppport named arguments](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/named_params).

This will allow passing arguments in a different order as long as you provide their name when calling.

E.g. this may look like:

```
class SomeDto
{
    public function __construct(
        public int $foo = 'foo',
        public string $bar = 'bar',
        public string $baz = 'baz',
    ) {}
}

$example = new SomeDto($bar = 'fnord!');
// will result in an object { foo: 'foo', bar: 'fnord!', baz: 'baz'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another method might be helpful for some is to pass a single argument as a string with 'key words', like...

```
    function foo($prms=""){
        isNAKED = (stripos(strtoupper($prms),"NAKED") !== false);
        showDETAILS = preg_match(...AS.NECESSARY...0)
        If (showDETAILS[0]){
           do what you do
        }
    }
```

Then your parameters can be in any order, can be missing all together, and the letter case is insignificant.  You can decide up-front how to encode passed values: DETAILS=6 or DETAILS(6) or anything else.

So, foo("NAKED DETAILS(6)") would work, or foo("DETAILS(6) NAKED") would work.  It can also be made to work with something like this...

foo("C=3,A=1,B=1");

or - foo("C=$C,A=1,B=$SOMETHINGELSEALLTOGETHERDIFFERENT");

It does require the code to parse-out the values

I find this most effective when passing (and detecting the presence of) key words (like 'NAKED' above)

Comment: But why would you use this instead of passing the arguments in an associative array? This seems like an over-complicated solution when compared to just using the associative array.

Answer (score 0):

No, not using the standrad php syntax.

There are always tricks for that of course, like if you are defining the function yourself, you could do something like

```
F(array('C'=>3, 'A'=>1, 'B'=>1));
```

But for that you would have to rewrite the original function of course, so that it would accept an array as arguments, as opposed to just accepting the arguments themselves.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. Something I've done for functions where many parameters are optional or I don't want order to matter is to instead use a single array parameter.

```
function myfunc( $options ) {
     $one = $options['one'];
     $two = $options['two'];
     // etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#8978)...

If you prefer to use named arguments to your functions (so you don't have to worry about the order of variable argument lists), you can do so PERL style with anonymous arrays:

```
<?php
function foo($args)
{
    print "named_arg1 : " . $args["named_arg1"] . "\n";
    print "named_arg2 : " . $args["named_arg2"] . "\n";
}

foo(array("named_arg1" => "arg1_value", "named_arg2" => "arg2_value"));
?>
```

will output:

```
named_arg1 : arg1_value
named_arg2 : arg2_value
```

Answer (score 0):

from php [site](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list):

In PHP 5.6 and later, argument lists may include the ... token to denote that the function accepts a variable number of arguments. The arguments will be passed into the given variable as an array; for example:

```
<?php
function sum(...$numbers) {
    $acc = 0;
    foreach ($numbers as $n) {
        $acc += $n;
    }
    return $acc;
}

echo sum(1, 2, 3, 4);
?>
```

Accompanied with post-process by **[instanceof](https://www.php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.instanceof.php)** or **[is_subclass_of](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-subclass-of.php)**  as in [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.instanceof.php#109108)(below):

```
class Foo {

    public $foobar = 'Foo';

    public function test() {
        echo $this->foobar . "\n";
    }

}

class Bar extends Foo {

    public $foobar = 'Bar';

}

$a = new Foo();
$b = new Bar();

echo "use of test() method\n";
$a->test();
$b->test();

echo "instanceof Foo\n";
var_dump($a instanceof Foo); // TRUE
var_dump($b instanceof Foo); // TRUE

echo "instanceof Bar\n";
var_dump($a instanceof Bar); // FALSE
var_dump($b instanceof Bar); // TRUE

echo "subclass of Foo\n";
var_dump(is_subclass_of($a, 'Foo')); // FALSE
var_dump(is_subclass_of($b, 'Foo')); // TRUE

echo "subclass of Bar\n";
var_dump(is_subclass_of($a, 'Bar')); // FALSE
var_dump(is_subclass_of($b, 'Bar')); // FALSE

?>

Result (CLI, 5.4.4):

use of test() method
Foo
Bar
instanceof Foo
bool(true)
bool(true)
instanceof Bar
bool(false)
bool(true)
subclass of Foo
bool(false)
bool(true)
subclass of Bar
bool(false)
bool(false)
```