# Quickbooks not executing request by priority

Tags: php, quickbooks, qbxml

I'm using QuickBooks SDK to sync orders between QuickBooks and my Volusion site. For that, I've created 6 different kinds of requests and it is executed by some priority. Below you can see my requests.

```
$Queue->enqueue(QUICKBOOKS_IMPORT_ITEM, QB_PRIORITY_ITEM);
$Queue->enqueue(QUICKBOOKS_IMPORT_SALESORDER, QB_PRIORITY_SALESORDER);
$Queue->enqueue(QUICKBOOKS_ADD_CUSTOMER, QB_PRIORITY_ADD_CUSTOMER);
$Queue->enqueue(QUICKBOOKS_ADD_INVENTORYITEM, QB_PRIORITY_ADD_ITEM);
$Queue->enqueue(QUICKBOOKS_ADD_SALESORDER,QB_PRIORITY_ADD_SALESORDER);
$Queue->enqueue(QUICKBOOKS_IMPORT_CUSTOMER, QB_PRIORITY_CUSTOMER);
```

And priorities for these requests are as follows

```
define('QB_PRIORITY_CUSTOMER', 1);
define('QB_PRIORITY_ITEM', 2);
define('QB_PRIORITY_SALESORDER', 3);
define('QB_PRIORITY_ADD_CUSTOMER', 4);
define('QB_PRIORITY_ADD_ITEM', 5);
define('QB_PRIORITY_ADD_SALESORDER', 6);
```

So as per my knowledge requests should follow these priorities. Suppose priority for QUICKBOOKS_IMPORT_CUSTOMER request is 1 so it should be the first one to be executed no matter if it's placed at last. As one can see I have that request at the end of all the requests(first code block) even though it's at the end it is executing first so it's fine.

Now one can see there is QUICKBOOKS_ADD_INVENTORYITEM request whose priority is 5. But the problem is it's not executing when I run the web connector(I'm using this to sync data between QB and Volusion) for the first time.

When I run web connector for the consequent time, execution starts from that method (QUICKBOOKS_ADD_INVENTORYITEM) and then the rest of the method is executing. I don't know why this is happening. I cleared database 3 times and tried to sync again but it's not working.

So please help me. I'm using QuickBooks Desktop Enterprise 19 and web connector 2.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameters you're passing to the function are incorrect. If you look at the function signature:

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/QuickBooks/WebConnector/Queue.php#L190

You can see that the *3rd parameter* is the priority:

`public function enqueue($action, $ident = null, $priority = 0, $extra = null, $user = null, $qbxml = null, $replace = true)`

While you're trying to pass in your priority as the *2nd parameter*:

`$Queue->enqueue(QUICKBOOKS_IMPORT_ITEM, QB_PRIORITY_ITEM);`

Fix your code:

`$Queue->enqueue(QUICKBOOKS_IMPORT_ITEM, null, QB_PRIORITY_ITEM);`

Also, note that *higher priorities run first*. e.g. this statement that you made is *incorrect*. In your example, the *sales order* would run first because it has the *highest* priority:

`Suppose priority for QUICKBOOKS_IMPORT_CUSTOMER request is 1 so it should be the first one to be executed no matter if it's placed at last.`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But if this is the case then why other methods are working correctly? Do I need to put null in that requests also?

Comment: Yes, PHP requires that you specify parameters in the correct order. I would recommend some reading on PHP functions: https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php and this may also be helpful to understand the concepts around calling functions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636073/can-php-function-parameters-be-passed-in-different-order-as-defined-in-declarati

Comment: I've inserted null in requests but the same issue happens. Above solution is not working.

Comment: Added another note about priorities -- higher priorities run _first_. If you continue to have trouble, please post your updated code _and_ a dump of the `quickbooks_queue` table showing the priorities and dequeue date/times that show it running in the wrong order.

Comment: Thanks for it Keith but now I have another question. How can I return blank XML from the request? Because I have one scenario where if certain conditions don't meet, a blank XML get sent. But because of that, my response method doesn't get executed so my whole execution stops there (I've 6 requests as per above). So my next requests don't get executed at all. So please help me with this.

Comment: `return QUICKBOOKS_NOOP;`